# How to achieve this raising 3d-style type in AE?

Tags: 3d, adobe-after-effects

I've been sent this (image of video attached) by a client and I'm trying to recreate it so I can add some extra wording to the animation. The text raises word by word, with the 3d shadow extending out with it.
I've managed to get the black outline and 3d shadow by adding Stroke and then Repeater with 55 copies at a 0.3 angle. The words are converted from text to shape. I just can't for the life of me figure out how to extend the letters HIGHER. When I add more copies to the Repeater, it extends the shapes backwards (away from the viewer) instead of pushing the letter towards the viewer.

Hope I'm making sense. Thank you for your help!
[image: Screenshot from video they have sent me]

Comment: http://video.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Video editing questions and video software questions are off-topic here. Try Video Production Stack Exchange.,